# When is a full sub-2-category not a full subcategory?

Tags: definition, higher-category-theory

nLab's page on [full sub-2-categories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/full+sub-2-category) says the following:

> If $C$ and $D$ are ordinary categories regarded as 2-categories, a full sub 2-category $F : C \hookrightarrow D$ is equivalently a full subcategory of $D$.

I'm confused by the word choice. Can't a 2-category always be regarded as a 1-category by forgetting its 1-transfors (its natural transformations, etc.)? So, shouldn't all full sub-2-categories be full subcategories as well?

Comment: Isn't that what it says? It says a full sub 2-category is equivalently a full subcategory.

Comment: This should either be simple or painfully nuanced, and I can't tell which. Two interesting nuances: first, the wording suggests that $F$ is the sub-2-category, and not $C$? Second, the page "sub-2-category" redirects to "full sub-2-category"; are there no non-full sub-2-categories? I admit ignorance.

Comment: @SridharRamesh: But then why "if"? Is it possible for the antecedent to fail?

Comment: Oh, I see what you're asking now. The point is, with a general 2-category, which may have non-identity 2-cells, we have a different notion of full sub-2-category than of full subcategory.

The two notions only coincide if the 2-category happens to have come from "promoting" a 1-category, and thus has no non-identity 2-cells.

Comment: So, yes, all full sub-2-categories comprise full subcategories as well (when we forget all the 2-cell structure and re-look at everything as 1-categories). But the reverse implication does not hold, because the notion of a full sub-2-category does indeed involve conditions on the 2-cell structure.

Comment: This is an answer to the question, not just a comment. Please post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list (otherwise it will be bumped up periodically). Also notice that comments are not indexed by the full text search, don't have any revision history, can only be edited for 5 minutes and allow only limited markup. Comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the problem. See [How do comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) for more information. @SridharRamesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a general 2-category, which may have non-identity 2-cells, we have a different notion of full sub-2-category than of full subcategory. The two notions only coincide if the 2-category happens to have come from "promoting" a 1-category, and thus has no non-identity 2-cells.

So, yes, all full sub-2-categories comprise full subcategories as well (when we forget all the 2-cell structure and re-look at everything as 1-categories). But the reverse implication does not hold, because the notion of a full sub-2-category does indeed involve conditions on the 2-cell structure.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this situation. I'll reword nLab to be less confusing.